# Public URL of a PHP page

Tags: php, href, dir

When accessing

```
www.example.com/test1/test2/index.php
```

(the file is `/var/www/website1/test1/test2/index.php` on server)

we get:

```
<base href="<?php echo __DIR__; ?>">  
// bad:  <base href="/var/www/website1/test1/test2/">

<base href="<?php echo dirname($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>">
// bad: <base href="/test1/test2">
//      a <base href> dir must end with a / (or \ on Windows)

<base href="<?php echo rtrim(dirname(parse_url($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], PHP_URL_PATH)), '/') . '/'; ?>">  
// good:  <base href="/test1/test2/">
```

**The last solution works (*), but I find it a bit dirty / a hack. Is there a cleaner solution to set `<base href="...">` the the current PHP file's dir ?**

*(*) In fact, the last solution doesn't work for Windows servers, because adding '/' breaks the `<base href>` (it should be '\').*

Comment: What value do you need ? isn't clear on you question.

Comment: @PedroLobito I want to set `<base href="...">` the the current PHP file's dir  (this dir must end with `/` or `\ ` depending on the plaform)

Comment: Check my answer, does any of the 3 options work for you ?

Comment: You can use `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` PHP constant which is dynamically loaded depending on your platform instead of slash/backslash it this is only your problem.

Comment: @LukasHajdu it seems that this is the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29731957/php-dirname-with-windows-platform

Answer (score 0):

```
dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
```

Should work. Otherwise do this:

**In PHP < 5.3:**

```
substr(dirname(__FILE__), strlen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']));
```

**Or PHP >= 5.3:**

```
substr(__DIR__, strlen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']));
```

---

**Update based on your comments:**

Use the solution that works on `linux`, if the script is running on windows modify the path accordingly.

**Deteting the server OS:**

```
if (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === 'WIN') {
    echo 'This is a server using Windows!';
} else {
    echo 'This is a server not using Windows!';
}
```

OR

```
if (DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR == '/') {
    // linux
}

if (DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR == '\\') {
    // windows
}
```

Comment: The problem is that, in order to be a `<base href="">`, we need a trailing slash or antislash